# Highlighting an item in the actionbar when in a certain activity when using ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android-layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm putting the final touches on an application that Ive been working on for quite a while and while I understand how to restyle existing components by using inheritance Im coming up blank in my search on how to accomplish this last thing.

I want to apply a custom color/image behind the text or icon representing the current activity I am in. This would be similar to how the tabs have the highlight underneath them while selected. I am already using the tabs and have figured out how to change the image resource that is the little underline in the tab bar. Now I just need to accomplish the same look for the action items.

Ive overlooked the actionbarsherlock library for the past day and a half but I dont see anywhere that I could do what I want to accomplish. I have to imagine that such a thing can be done but like I said before so far Im coming up short. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a simple way to do what I asked earlier. I just created a square shape in xml, put text over it, assigned it the gradient and color I wanted and assigned it to that action item I wanted highlighted in the activity i was in.